# Change Password in Extended Directory Catalog

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I use the standard password change function from domino to change the password in an extended directory catalog.

So I open this link in a browser: http://serverurl/names_extended.nsf?ChangePassword

I type the old password and the new password twice, but the password is not changed in the person document.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: How could that work? The extended catalog is an aggregation of multiple directories, you need to change the password in the orignal database....

Comment: Oh, sorry maybe I interchanged the terms. With extended directory catalog I mean an extended names.nsf.

Comment: Did you check admin requests?

Comment: There is an Error which says: Error: A person document for either the request’s signer or the ‘Name(s) acted upon’ was not found in any local trusted directories for which this server is the Administration Server. I already googled for it but none of the proposed fixes would help.

Comment: Check your directory assistance... is names_extended trusted for credentials? Does names_extended have the right adminserver in the acl?

Comment: In the Naming Contexts(Rules) Tab the first line (N.C.1) is filled all the way with "*" and Enabled = Yes and Trusted for Credentials = Yes.
In the Domino Tab There is nothing for Application links, but for Replica 1 there is the server and the path names_extended and enabled = yes.

Comment: and what about the adminserver in acl of names_extended?

Comment: I added the Adminserver (the server which is raising the error in the admin requests) as a Manager to the acl of the names_extended.nsf. Does this server need access in the directory assistance as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135151/discussion-between-torsten-link-and-mememax).